# About the function $f(x)=\sin x\ln x^2$ and derivative definition

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, definition, intuition

$f(x)=\begin {cases}\sin x\ln x^2 & x\neq 0\\ 0 & x=0\end{cases}$

When I try to find the derivative on $x=0$ with the defintion I get:

$\displaystyle\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(h+0)-f(0)}{h-0}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {f(h)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac {\sin h \ln h^2} h=\lim_{h\to 0}\ln h^2=-\infty$

But I see from the graph that the slope on $x=0$ is supposed to be finite:

[image]

Why does the derivative definition don't work here?

Comment: That's not the definition of derivative!

Comment: @Caddyshack yes it is, I added the first step.

Comment: Let me edit this to be more close to the function I have. @GitGud

Comment: What program did you use to generate the graph? (You are correct, the derivative at $0$ doesn't exist.)

Comment: It's desmos.com @mrf but why? seeing from the graph it should have a derivative there...

Comment: From the graph I don't necessarily see it as finite. What I see is that the 'tangent' is the $y$-axis and one gets to that tangent by negative slopes, hence $-\infty$.

Comment: @GitGud oh right it's an infliction point...

Comment: Computer programs usually draw graphs by computing a lot of points on the curve, and then connecting them with straight lines. Vertical tangents will then usually show up as steep, but not quite vertical. You should always be a little careful with relying too heavily on computer-generated graphs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the function $f$ defined by $f(x) = \sin x \ln(x^2)$ is an odd function. $f$ is continuous at $x = 0$ and $$f(x) = 2x \ln x \text{ for } x \to 0+$$  the one sided derivative $$D_+f\rvert_0 = \lim_{x \to 0+}  \frac{f(x)}{x} = \frac{2x\ln x }{x} = 2 \ln x = dne$$

the reason this is not obvious from your graph is the function $\ln x$ go to $-\infty$ much slower than say $1/x.$  if you zoom in around zero more and more you will see the slope getting bigger.

another way is to take the derivative of $x\ln x.$  you will find that $(x\ln x)' = 1+\ln x \to -\infty \text { as } x \to 0+ $

there is no difference in the limiting behaviors of $\sin x \ln(x^2) $ and $2x\ln x$ as $x \to 0+$. that is why i took the simpler one.